# Query DB to non entity type classes using EF Core

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have an ASP.NET Core 7 app with EF Core 7. I need to query some tables from a database which is not in my control, and I don't even have the `dbcontext`, but I have the connection string to the database.

I need to query some table from that database using EF Core 7 to some DTO which are not entity types. I have tried with Dapper and it works, but how to achieve the same thing with EF Core?

Comment: Is there any DbContext available. What does "I dont have the DbConext" mean?

Comment: "I dont have the DbConext" means the required project that contains the class which inherits the ef core DbContext is not available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use my SqlQuery nuget library; https://www.nuget.org/packages/ErikEJ.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.SqlQuery/7.0.0-preview1

```
var context = new ChinookContext();

var result = await context.SqlQueryAsync<MyDto>("SELECT * FROM MyTable");
```

Comment: thanks a lot i will give it a try?. is it not directly possible using ef coore 7 though?

Comment: That is correct. But my package is just a tint wrspper